# Why does Jeremiah refer to Zedekiah as Jehoiakim?

Tags: contradiction, chronology, jeremiah

In Jeremiah 27 the chapter begins by discussing the beginning of the reign of Jehoiakim, but in verse 3 pivots to talking about Zedekiah.

> 1 In the **beginning of the reign of Jehoiakim** the son of Josiah king of
> Judah came this word unto Jeremiah from the Lord, saying,
>
> 2 Thus saith the Lord to me; Make thee bonds and yokes, and put them
> upon thy neck,
>
> 3 And send them to the king of Edom, and to the king of Moab, and to
> the king of the Ammonites, and to the king of Tyrus, and to the king
> of Zidon, by the hand of the messengers which **come to Jerusalem unto
> Zedekiah king of Judah**;

The subsequent record appears to confirm we're talking about King Zedekiah, not King Jehoiakim. (Jer. 27:12, 28:1)

Why does Jeremiah refer to the same king with the names Zedekiah & Jehoiakim? Is Zedekiah a name by which multiple kings were known? Or is the name of the king in verse 1 or 3 an error?

Comment: Zedekiah succeeded the two kings named Jehoiakim, a father and a son, whose reigns preceded the Babylonian invasion. Either we are dealing with a prophecy concerning future events, or Zedekiah is called king anachronistically (like referring to Bush Jr. as President Bush in a biography, even when treating events in his life that preceded his presidency).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the standard MT has Jehoiakim.  The BSB and many modern versions have "Zedekiah".  The BSB has this footnote:

> A few Hebrew manuscripts and Syriac (see also verses 3 and 12, and
> Jeremiah 28:1); most Hebrew manuscripts Jehoiakim

Ellicott expresses a possible explanation:

> (1) In the beginning of the reign of Jehoiakim.—The mention of the
> name of Zedekiah as king of Judah in Jeremiah 27:3 shows that the
> Hebrew text has here perpetuated an error, due probably to the
> transcriber or first editor of the collected prophecies. We have to
> think, accordingly, of the state of things which followed on the death
> of Jehoiakim, and the deposition and exile of Jehoiachin. The tone of
> the prophecy seems to indicate a time about the middle of Zedekiah’s
> reign. His position was that of a tributary sovereign, subject to
> Nebuchadnezzar. He and the neighbouring kings, who were in a like
> position, had not quite renounced the hope of throwing off the yoke,
> and asserting their independence.

Benson makes similar comments:

> Jeremiah 27:1. In the beginning of the reign of Jehoiakim — Instead of
> Jehoiakim here, Dr. Waterland, Houbigant, Blaney, and many others,
> read Zedekiah, because it is difficult, if not impossible, to
> reconcile the common reading with what follows. Lowth also, in his
> commentary upon the place, gives it as his opinion, that “the least
> forced way of solving the difficulty is, to say that Jehoiakim has
> crept into the text by the negligence of the scribes, (who might have
> their eyes fixed upon the beginning of the last chapter or section,)
> instead of Zedekiah. This emendation is confirmed by comparing this
> verse with the 3d, 12th, and 20th verses of this chapter, and with the
> beginning of the next. Such little verbal mistakes must be allowed by
> all impartial readers to have sometimes happened in transcribing the
> Holy Scriptures, as well as in other books, and may easily be
> corrected, by comparing the suspected reading with other parts of the
> sacred text, which admit of no difficulty or uncertainty.”

Other commentators offer similar remarks.

Comment: It could not have been an exposition by the narrator(for verse 12), or else prophecy? 'it must have been an error'

Comment: @Dottard thank you for the helpful textual analysis. BTW, congrats on the reputation milestone.

Comment: @HoldToTheRod - many thanks - you noticed before I did.